# JavaFX Animations: Quit an infinite transition by fading out

Tags: animation, javafx, transition

Have an animation like this starting with the program:

```
tr = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(1000), rect);
tr.setFromValue(0.5);
tr.setToValue(0.1);
tr.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
tr.setAutoReverse(true);
```

Obviously it loops endlessly. Now I want a function which stops this, but only after it has faded out. that means just the next time it reaches its "to value" (or the "from value") it should stop animating.

Now I know that I can end the animation on the next iteration by setting the cycle count to 1. However that only works when the animation has been stopped before.

```
tr.stop();
tr.setCycleCount(1);
tr.play();
```

But that means the .play() function restarts the animation, causing a flicker which isn't really pretty. This last cycle doesn't continue where it had been before.

How can I end the animation smoothly?

Huge thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have found a smooth solution myself after all.
Instead of using infinite cycle, it uses a cycle of 2 and a finish-event which just restarts the animation:

```
tr = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(1000), rect);
tr.setFromValue(0.1);
tr.setToValue(0.5);
tr.setAutoReverse(true);
tr.setCycleCount(2);
tr.play();

tr.setOnFinished((ActionEvent event) -> tr.play());
```

Then a simple call of

```
tr.setOnFinished(null);
```

Suffices to smoothly quit the animation at the end of the last transition.